# HTML doesn't upload on google chrome properly

Tags: html, google-chrome

so i'm trying to learn HTML with CSS and usually I opened the files on Microsoft Edge,
and then I tried to open them on Google Chrome, but for some reason only some portion of the code is loaded correctly, and some of it just not visible.
How can this happen? And what is the solution?
thanks.
[screenshot of the page, in the middle there should be an image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/awHnW.png

HTML:

```
<section name="second-sec" id="second-section" style="z-index: 0;">
        <div class="grid" title="steak" style="background-image: url(/images/steak.jpg);"></div>
        <div class="grid" title="falafel" style="background-image:url(/images/falafel.jpg);"></div>
        <div class="grid" title="soup" style="background-image:url(/images/soup.jpg);"></div>
        <div class="grid" title="sniztel" style="background-image:url(/images/shniztel.jpg);"></div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
#second-section {
    background-image: url("/images/wood-pic.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    height: 10000px;
}
.grid {
    display:inline-block;
    background-size: cover;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    background-position:center;
    margin-bottom:-3.5px;
}
.grid:hover {
    border: 1.5px solid #adacac;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
}
```

**Okay**, so i opened inspect and for some reason it show that file couldn't found, maybe it's because i use url() and inside i entered a local path?
The images are saved on my computer.

Comment: can you screenshot of the output which you getting?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, i added a link to the screenshot (stackverflow doesn't allow me yet to add images).

Comment: can you share your code too?

Comment: With screenshot?

Comment: don't paste code screenshot Edit your question.

Comment: Open Inspect Tools on chrome and select the image and see if the link is proper. Maybe chrome is messing with image link path. If you don't know how to use inspect tool: https://progate.com/docs/html-dev

Answer (score 0):

You can set google chrome of your index.html file to Google Chrome in properties section and then try. If you have also problem there. Provide the screenshot or attached snippet of your code. There is issue also with Microsoft Edge and html vice versa. You can check here and get the solution, there:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/edge-wont-open-htmhtml-files-from-my-network/7195426c-5d6f-4b16-9f43-e70d2a25fdfb

I prefer to choose google chrome to see the output of the code of my targeted file.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the browser couldn't find the files when I used:

`"background-image: url(/images/steak.jpg);"`

But when I added 2 dots to the path as follows it actually worked:

`"background-image: url(../images/steak.jpg);"`